# Why am I getting two different record count when I use a datetime type column enclosed in function date( ) and without date( )?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL 8.0, its "Sakila" database and the table "rentals".

```
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| rental_id    | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| rental_date  | datetime              | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| inventory_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| customer_id  | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| return_date  | datetime              | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| staff_id     | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| last_update  | timestamp             | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I ran these two commands on the same table and counted the records returned using count() function.

```
select count(*) from rental where date(rental_Date) between '2005-06-14' AND '2005-06-16';
```

```
Output:
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      688 |
+----------+
```

```
select count(*) from rental where rental_Date between '2005-06-14' AND '2005-06-16';
```

```
Output:
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      364 |
+----------+
```

I'm not sure what happened behind the scenes, but I was actually anticipating that the count to be same from both queries, as the `rental_Date` column is of type `datetime` and in the 2nd query I extracted the **date** part from the column `rental_date` to be used as my `where` condition.

Could someone please help me understand what happened here.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If rental_date is `2005-06-16 12:00:00`, it is not between your two dates, but `date(rental_date)` is `2005-06-16` which is between them.

So the date() query includes all datetimes on the 16th, but the other query only includes those with a time component of midnight.

Comment: Yeah that make sense. Thanks @ysth.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, DateTime and Date are different types.
DateTime contains time and offset information and Date does not.
When you cast your DateTime data into Date. You are losing precision which is why you are getting different results.

For more details please see: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=The%20DATE%20type%20is%20used,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=The%20DATE%20type%20is%20used,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts).